# Lighttpd mod_rewrite and SSL

Tags: ssl, mod-rewrite, https, lighttpd

I'm trying to prevent the search engines from crawling through SSL version of the site, to prevent content duplication and canonization issues.

I found the following great article:
http://www.seoworkers.com/seo-articles-tutorials/robots-and-https.html

Problem is, that I'm using lighttpd, which doesn't seem to have the RewriteCond directive, to limit the rewriting only to SSL.

Can anyone advice if this possible on lighttpd, and give a snippet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "a.b.c.d:443" {
  ...

  $HTTP["host"] =~ "<yourhostname>" {
    url.rewrite-once = ("^robots.txt$" => "robots_ssl.txt")
  }
}
```

the `url.rewrite-once` should definitely be in your `$SERVER["socket"]` section of your ssl part to be only applied when your ssl host is accessed.

url.rewirte-once can be placed [without](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/docs:modrewrite) conditional but it seems that it will not work all the time according to some forums.

Comment: Hi.

Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it didn't work.

I still getting the old robots.txt.

Any idea?

Comment: dump questions first ;) have you restarted? when yes, try to vary the regex: `url.rewrite-once = ("^/robots.txt$" => "/robots_ssl.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least version 1.4.19 you should be able to use conditional configuration, with something like:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
     url.rewrite-once = ("^robots.txt$" => "robots_ssl.txt")
}
```

Comment: Hi.

Just tried this - doesn't work, still getting the original robots.txt page.

I placed this snippet outside the $SERVER["socket"] block.

I use lighttpd 1.4.22, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Any suggestions?